# Слово "причастие"

Tags: этимология

"Причастие" как христианский обряд — это мне понятно: стать *частью* Бога. Но почему причастием еще называется часть речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Часть речи, **причастная к глаголу**, в образе прилагательного» В. И. Даль.